# PlaneGeometry Mesh gives black screen in Three.JS

Tags: three.js

I am newbie to ThreeJS. I want to set BG image for a Scene, I got only blank (black) screen when i run this following code.

Could any one tell me what was the problem in following code?

```
$().ready(function(){

    var width= window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    renderer.setSize( width, height );
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    renderer.setClearColorHex(0xffffff, 1.0);
    // renderer.clear(); 


    /*SEttingup BG*/
    var bg = new THREE.Mesh(
      new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2, 0,0),
      new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("2/bharatpriyankaweddingphotography (6).jpg")})
    );

    // The bg plane shouldn't care about the z-buffer.
    bg.materials[0].depthTest = false;
    bg.materials[0].depthWrite = false;
    console.log(bg);
    var bgScene = new THREE.Scene();
    var bgCam = new THREE.Camera();
    bgScene.add(bgCam);
    bgScene.add(bg);

    // renderer.autoClear = false;
    renderer.clear();
    renderer.render(bgScene, bgCam);
    // renderer.render(scene, cam);

    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your canvas is going to use up the whole window, then you could also just set the background via CSS.  For example:

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image:url('foo.jpg');
  background-color:blue;  
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

By the sounds of this, i believe that you want to use a shader to project the plane to the screen and use it as a background. This is not as straightforward as it may seem and as far as i know three.js will require a custom shader, (unless you want to mess around with projection matrices in three.js).

The shader itself is very simple, i have recently answered a similar question on the webgl facebook group, pasting the answer:

```
var yourPlaneGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2,2,1,1);
```

shader

```
varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
vUv = uv;
vec4 transformedPos = vec4( position.xy, 0.01, 1.0 );
gl_Position = transformedPos;
}
```

this will render the standard three.js plane as a full screen quad

```
//read the uv value from the vertex shader
varying vec2 vUv;
uniform sampler2D yourTexture; 
void main(){
vec3 tex = texture2d(yourTexture,vUv).xyz;
gl_FragColor = vec4(tex, 1.0);
}
```

you need to create a shaderMaterial with these two as vertex and fragment shader, and you might want to set the depth test to false

Answer (score 0):

Your camera does not have position or target.